# When I add an image to a WYGWAM field, using Assets, from an S3 source, I get a double slash

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, wygwam, s3

I chose an image from a regular upload directory and it works fine. I chose one from an S3 source set up in Assets, and it doesn't. 
For instance:

```
<img alt="" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/foursquare.org//1350928362-IMG_3335.PNG" />
```

The double slash is causing the image not to display.

I'm using WYGWAM 2.7.1, EE 2.6.1, Assets 2.1.4, and a lot of Scotch at this point.

Comment: Travis, Scotch has been known to resolve many troubles.

Are you using the subfolder setting for the S3 source?

Comment: No, I'm not using the subfolder setting.

Comment: Travis, are you still having this issue?

Comment: No, I am not. P&T resolved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by Pixel&Tonic for me.